How to change the background image in SDDM login - KDE - Kubuntu 24.04?
I was trying to change the background screen in the SDDM login in KDE - Kubuntu 24.04 using the system manager, but it was not keeping the changes after closing the manager.

The following worked for me:
In the file:
/usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze/theme.conf

I edit the line:
background=/usr/share/wallpapers/Kay/contents/images_dark/5120x2880.png

and point to another image in the /usr/share/wallpapers with the commands:
cd /usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze
ls
sudo nano theme.conf

I also changed the image 5120x2880.png within the /usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze/ folder:
cd /usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze
rm 5120x2880.png
cp /usr/share/wallpapers/Kay/contents/images_dark/5120x2880.png /usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze

Some sources
archlinux wiki
and
archlinux org
Disclaimer: It is not advised to change SDDM with root privileges, source: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/sddm-config-location.79830/, so it is at your own risk and responsibility.
